# Remove element from an array based on it's multiple peoperties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, iteration

I've an array of elements as follows

**entities**

```
[
  {
    "name":"tiger",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"animal"
  },
  {
    "name":"cat",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"animal"
  },
{
    "name":"parrot",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"bird"
  },{
    "name":"potato",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"vegetable"
  },
  {
    "name":"orange",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"fruit"
  },
  {
    "name":"orange",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"colour"
  }
]
```

I've another array which is as follows

**elemToRemove**

```
[orange@fruit,cat@animal,tiger@animal]
```

I want to remove the elements having `name=orange` and `type=fruit`, `name=cat` and `type=animal`, `name=tiger` and `type=animal`

It is easily possible to remove the element based on single property by using filter over the array but in this case I am not able to put up map/filter/reduce to remove these elements.

I used split to create a name and type array and tried to do this but as we've type repeating the condition always returned false.

```
 let nameArray = elemToRemove.map(function (elem) {
    return elem.split('@')[0];
  });

  let typeArray= elemToRemove.map(function (elem) {
    return elem.split('@')[1];
  });

  var reqData= entities.filter(function (obj) {
    return (nameArray.indexOf(obj.name) === -1 && typeArray.indexOf(obj['env']) === -1);
  });
```

Thus always giving me an empty reqData array. I do not have a provision to have an id or else I could've used id to delete the elements.

**Expected Output**

```
[
    {
        "name":"parrot",
        "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
        "type":"bird"
      },{
        "name":"potato",
        "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
        "type":"vegetable"
      },
      {
        "name":"orange",
        "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
        "type":"colour"
      }
    ]
```

What is most elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: First _There is really no such thing as a "JSON Object"._

Comment: When you say `I am not able to put up map/filter/reduce` you mean you can't use them? Or you don't know how?

Comment: Oh I mean I tried to use filter/map/reduce in a way or other as mentioned in the code snippet but failed to get an working output, I am allowed to use absolutely anything it is not a test or homework :D

Comment: @Usman thanks for pointing out, I'll edit it right away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) tends to be useful for these sorts of problems with the bonus of `sublinear` value retrieval.

```js
// Input.
const input = [{"name":"tiger","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"animal"},{"name":"cat","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"animal"},{"name":"parrot","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"bird"},{"name":"potato","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"vegetable"},{"name":"orange","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"fruit"},{"name":"orange","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"colour"}]

// Tags.
const tags = ["orange@fruit", "cat@animal", "tiger@animal"]

// Clean.
const clean = (array, tags) => {
  const map = new Map(array.map(x => [`${x.name}@${x.type}`, x])) // Create Map.
  tags.forEach(tag => map.delete(tag)) // Remove each tag from Map.
  return Array.from(map.values()) // Return Array from Map.values().
}

// Output.
const output = clean(input, tags)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```

Comment: This answer could definitely benefit from some explanation; the "clean" function is concise to the point of impenetrability to someone who doesn't already have a good understanding of Map and etc

Comment: Bad habit. I agree  Refactoring. @DanielBeck

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it's good code!  Just kind of hard to follow for non-experts

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` to select only those objects which doesn't match desired criteria. We will test each object using `.some()` to find if there any match found between object and the array having strings to check.

```js
let data = [{"name":"tiger", "imageurl":"https://someurl.com", "type":"animal"}, {"name":"cat", "imageurl":"https://someurl.com", "type":"animal"}, {"name":"parrot", "imageurl":"https://someurl.com", "type":"bird"}, { "name":"potato", "imageurl":"https://someurl.com", "type":"vegetable"}, { "name":"orange", "imageurl":"https://someurl.com", "type":"fruit"}, { "name":"orange", "imageurl":"https://someurl.com", "type":"colour"}];

let arr = ['orange@fruit', 'cat@animal', 'tiger@animal'];

let result = data.filter(o => !arr.some(s => (
    [name, type] = s.split('@'),
    o['name'] === name && o['type'] === type
)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Why would someone downvote this answer? it is valid and produces the expected result!

Comment: I don't see a reason for downvotes either it does get the desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.filter`:

```js
var arr = [
  {"name":"tiger","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"animal"},
  {"name":"cat","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"animal"},
  {"name":"parrot","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"bird"},
  {"name":"potato","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"vegetable"},
  {"name":"orange","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"fruit"},
  {"name":"orange","imageurl":"https://someurl.com","type":"colour"}
];

var toRemove = ['orange@fruit', 'cat@animal', 'tiger@animal'];
var filterOut = toRemove.map(e => { 
  var [name, type] = e.split('@');
  return {name, type};
});
arr = arr.filter(e => !filterOut.find(({name, type}) => e.name === name && e.type === type));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Why would someone downvote this answer? it is valid and produces the expected result!

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of *elegant* is to have the least possible code (to avoid human error), and reutilize elements that have been already created by others, I recommend using an external library like Lodash that already have a function to do this.

The first part if a bit complex since I'm parting from having a string:

`[orange@fruit,cat@animal,tiger@animal]`

that needs to be parsed, instead of having already an array of values like the other answers.

```
// First we need to convert the filter to a proper Json representation.
// This is needed since the _.remove function takes a Json object.
// This could be simplified if your filter string were already a
// Json object.
var filter = "[orange@fruit,cat@animal,tiger@animal]";
filter = filter.replace(/(\w+)@(\w+)[,\]]/g, (m, p1, p2, offset, string) => {
    return `{"name":"${p1}","type":"${p2}"}${m.includes(']')?']':','}`;
});
filter = JSON.parse(filter);


// Next, apply the filter to the remove function from Lodash.
// Once you have a Json object, it's only two lines of code.
const rm = _.partial(_.remove, obj);
filter.forEach(rm)
```

```js
var obj = [
  {
    "name":"tiger",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"animal"
  },
  {
    "name":"cat",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"animal"
  },
{
    "name":"parrot",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"bird"
  },{
    "name":"potato",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"vegetable"
  },
  {
    "name":"orange",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"fruit"
  },
  {
    "name":"orange",
    "imageurl":"https://someurl.com",
    "type":"colour"
  }
];

// First we need to convert the filter to a proper Json representation.
// This is needed since the _.remove function takes a Json object.
// This could be simplified if your filter string were already a
// Json object.
var filter = "[orange@fruit,cat@animal,tiger@animal]";
filter = filter.replace(/(\w+)@(\w+)[,\]]/g, (m, p1, p2, offset, string) => {
    return `{"name":"${p1}","type":"${p2}"}${m.includes(']')?']':','}`;
});
filter = JSON.parse(filter);


// Next, apply the filter to the remove function from Lodash.
// Once you have a Json object, it's only two lines of code.
const rm = _.partial(_.remove, obj);
filter.forEach(rm)

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```